# Does a Sober Scottish man really exists?

Tags: drinking, craft-beers, scotch

Does a Sober Scottish man really exists?

I recently being crazy about Scottish Culture, accent, land...

I noticed that every Scottish man loves his beer more than water is that true?

Comment: hi z00, It seems you'er new here. This stack exchange is for the discussion of alcohol, not cultural stereotypes. You may get a better response if you rephrase your question in a more technical way, or maybe approach it from a historical perspective (in which case this is the wrong stack exchange to post it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know plenty of Scots who are t-total or drink relatively little.

Additionally, there are loads of [additional Scottish licencing laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_licensing_laws_of_the_United_Kingdom) which are aimed to reduce binge drinking and have been shown to have a positive effect. [Source: The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2019/jun/19/scotland-alcohol-sales-lowest-level-25-years-price-controls)

In my personal experience (my boyfriend being himself half Scot and my Step-mum being full Scot) the Scottish actually drink less than the rest of the UK and definitely less than, say, the Welsh people I know. (I.e. myself and family before anyone has a go!)

In short: **Yes a sober Scottish man does exist**. Source: I know at least one.

Comment:   thanks  for sharing the info  i love Scottish people